# Paypal expressCheckout integration (DoExpressCheckout) error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, payment-gateway

I have a ExpressCheckout integration setup in java google app engine and it working up to GetExpresschekout .but in finall call(DoExpressCheckout) I am unable to Authorize payment .it returns
an error

RESULT=1000&PNREF=E24P1FBB8FA4&RESPMSG=Generic processor error: 13116-The transaction is in progress for this token.&AVSADDR=N&AVSZIP=N

but the same code is works in local but it is showing  above error in after deployment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works when testing locally, but that error simply means the user hasn't actually paid yet. This might be because the user really hasn't paid yet or because the transaction is pending verification. PayPal flags some transactions as risky and takes a few good hours to verify them.

Did you wait for the user to return to `RETURNURL` before executing `DoExpressCheckout()`? Did you verify the user didn't actually return to `CANCELURL`?

Did you verify with `GetTransactionDetails()` that `PAYMENTSTATUS` is `"Completed"` and not `"Pending"`? You can check `PendingReason" for more details. See [Payment Review](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOtherAPIOps) for more information on pending transactions.